# Get result as variable from Json output

Tags: php, json

I'm using a Recharge API. The API receives the response in Json format. I need to store a output value in variable from the Json response in PHP.

```
// Response received from API url  
$output = '{"data":[{"user":"abcd123","bal":"500","error_code":200,"resText":"Success"}]}';

//Decoding output  
$json = json_decode($output, true);

//Print
print_r($json);

//Store a value as variable  
$bal = $json['bal'];
```

> Getting error that **bal** is undefined index.

Please help me with the proper way to get the value of **bal** in the variable **$bal** from the API response.

Comment: `print_r($json);` and following the structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JSON object actually stores all of the data in an attribute called `data`, which is in turn an array of objects (just 1 really). So instead try

```
$json['data'][0]['bal']
```